# Why is $S^1 \times \mathbb R$ a trivial vector bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry

I looked for answers, but there seemed to be many terminologies for a beginner to understand, so I decided to ask one.

Given a vector bundle $\pi: S^1 \times \mathbb R \rightarrow S^1$, is it simply because
local trivialization $\Phi: S^1 \times \mathbb R \rightarrow S^1 \times \mathbb R$ (for example, I can take $\Phi = Id$) is smooth and the local trivialization is global?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A vector bundle over $X$ is trivial if it is $X\times \mathbb{R}^n$. It is trivializable (sometimes it is still called trivial) if it is isomorphic (as a vector bundle) to the trivial bundle. Your vector bundle is _the_ trivial bundle over $S^1$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fiber bundle $p \colon E \rightarrow B$ with fiber $F$ is a continuous map that comes with

$\bullet$ a base space $B$

$\bullet$ a total space $E$

$\bullet$ a topological space called fiber $F$

such that the map $p$ locally on $E$ is the projection $\text{pr}_1 \colon B \times F \rightarrow B$.

(The reason that I am telling you about fiber bundles is that vector bundles are certain fiber bundles.)

What is the easiest example of a fiber bundle? Well, that is given when we do not even have to care about the "local part", i.e. when the fiber bundle globally is the projection $\text{pr}_1 \colon B \times F \rightarrow B$. Such fiber bundles are called trivial. The same holds for vector bundles. So yes, the trivialization is global, as you said.